# UISuppressionMode in registry not affecting Lync Client

Tags: c#, lync, lync-2013

I am using custom C# Lync 2013 client with a sever i just recently setup. I need to develop a custom Lync Client that allows audio video conference. I found a really well explained demo [here](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/Lync-2013-Use-the-Lync-68eabecb).

Looking in the code i found discovered that i had to run the Lync Client in UISuppressionMode to allow the new C# Client to view the videos. So i did some searches and found it was a key in the registry that had to be edited/created. And so i did as i found in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AMs5nbmlyqc). I started Lync and added the registry entry at the good place for Lync 2013.

[image: Image of my registry Key and Value]

After, it needed to be closed and restarted.

But the Client UI started, like i had not changed a thing. I have been working on this for hours without any fixes. I will post it on the Lync's forum too, wishing for the best.

**UPDATE:**

From MSDN :

> You can set the Lync 2013 suppression mode when you install the Lync client. At the command prompt, start the Lync installation .exe with a command-line argument in the following table.

I tried using the Office install for Lync online with that command, and the arguments isn't valid.

```
Setup.exe /FullUisuppression
```

I downloaded Lync Basic client from the Windows Download center. Didn't work either.

```
lyncentry.exe /FullUisuppression
```

**UPDATE 2:**

I changed the Lync Client version to 2010 and the UiSuppresionMode works perfecly fine, but the demo i found uses the 2013 sdk. It can't find the LyncClient even if its running. I found another demo which uses the 2010 sdk and works fine. The documenting of 2010 is not really complete, or it might be almost the same as the 2013 sdk. I will look forward into the 2010 version but i would prefer the 2013 to be working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lync 2013 reads the setting for UISuppressionMode from a different registry key than Lync 2010. Since it works with 2010, but not 2013, I assume you use the wrong key. Try `[HKEY_CURRENT_USER]\Software\Microsoft\Office\15.0\Lync\UISuppressionMode`.

See also: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj933224%28v=office.15%29.aspx http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/office/jj265332%28v=office.15%29.aspx